# Trouble with margins and borders

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create two boxes that are 80% wide, including an 8px border. (unless I can create a % border, which I do not think you can) Now, when I set a 10% margin on the right and left sides of my boxes, they are off to the right by a few pixels. Is there a way to fix this?

HTML:

```
<div id="upcoming_show" class="front_page_item grid_8">
        <div class="left front_block_headline">
            <h2 class="upper_headline">Upcoming Show:</h2>
            <h1>The Walrus</h1>
        </div>
        <p>The Walrus is a show that truly shows the human spirit. The main character, Mickey, is found lying face down on a beach in the middle of...</p>
        <p><a href="#" class="btn right">Read More</a></p>
    </div>

    <div id="recent_post" class="front_page_item grid_8">
        <div class="left front_block_headline">
            <h2 class="upper_headline">Recent Post:</h2>
            <h1>GSA was a BLAST!</h1>
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
#upcoming_show {
    margin-right: 10%;
    margin-left: 10%;
    min-height: 200px;
}

#recent_post {
    margin-right: 10%;
    margin-left: 10%;
    min-height: 200px;
}

.front_page_item {
    text-align: center;
    border: 8px solid #C8C8C8;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand the issue. They look fine.

Comment: Yes i'm not sure what the issue is here. the fiddle is displaying fine for me.

Comment: It is not showing up correctly in my safari browser?

Answer (score 0):

Upcoming show has 2 right magins set.

Comment: My bad, I forgot that I had edited that. I was just trying but it still does not work.